# How to read from a text-file.

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I would like to know how can I check for a specific string on a line of a text file, save it in an array, and then move on to the next line of that text file.

For e.g.:
(what he is/ year edition/name/age/profession/number)

competitor 2014 joseph 21 student 20232341

competitor 2013 michael 23 engineer 23425123

As output, it would give me this:

**Song Festival'2014**

**here are the competitors:**

**Joseph, student of 21 years - 20232341**

**Song Festival'2013**

**are the competitors**

**Michael, engineer of 23 years - 23425123**

edit: java language

Comment: What language are you writting in?

Comment: oh, I'm writing on Java

Comment: Example added to my answer - please make sure to click the up arrow and the checkmark if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you would use a BufferedReader, you can format things in the text file using the tab (indent) which would be read from the BufferedReader as '\t' I'll write an example for you in a moment.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class StackoverflowExample {

    private static final int INFORMATION_CAP = 100;
    private static String[][] INFORMATION = new String[INFORMATION_CAP][INFORMATION_CAP];

    public StackoverflowExample() {
        String currentLine;
        String[] textData;
        int lineID = 0;
        boolean endOfFile = false;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
            while(!endOfFile && currentLine != null) {
                currentLine = currentLine.trim();
                textData = currentLine.split("\\t");
                String userType = textData[0];
                String year = textData[1];
                String name = textData[2];
                String age = textData[3];
                String profession = textData[4];
                String number = textData[5];
                INFORMATION[lineID] = new String[] { userType, year, name, age, profession, number };
                lineID++;
                currentLine = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StackoverflowExample();
        for(int i = 0; i < INFORMATION.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Type: " + INFORMATION[i][0] +
                    "year: " + INFORMATION[i][1] + 
                    "name: " + INFORMATION[i][2] + 
                    "age: " + INFORMATION[i][3] + 
                    "profession: " + INFORMATION[i][4] +
                    "number: " + INFORMATION[i][5]);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a text file called "textfile.txt" in your projects main directory, and format it like this

```
type(tab)year(tab)name(tab)age(tab)profession(tab)number(newline)
```